# Position: fixed; moves element to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a button:

```css
.b_next {
  border-radius: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100px;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: #cad2e7;
  color: #28284c;
  border-color: transparent;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.floatbtn {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="b_next floatbtn">Next</button>
```

It is in a content wrapper has:

```css
text-align: center;
```

However, my button is moved to the right when I add `position: fixed`, how do I fix this?

**Expected Output**

I want to button to be centered, at the bottom of the page, fixed.

Comment: Hi, where is your content wrapper? There is only a button, which have both classes. What is the desired behaviour? ;)

Comment: The button is 100px from the bottom of the content wrapper, but is off-centered by a hundred px or so. @Dave

Comment: can you provide the expected output also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not completely understand your question, but if you want to position it entirely to the left or right, you can apply `left: 0;` or `right: 0;` to `.floatbtn`.

**Update**

Ah, you've added your expected output, then you can use the following to align your button in the middle(center):

```
.floatbtn {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 100px;

    /* Below code aligns it to the center */
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Hi @WazowskiMan I've updated my answer to your new description.